# Creating a click function from a select element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having some trouble creating a JavaScript function using an select element and id link. The function should depend on the selected option/value of the select dropdon.

What I want to do, is call an event function when the select dropdown is clicked, then apply a class to the appropriate id.

The html is this:

```
<select class="select-trigger" >
   <option value="value1">Value1</option>
   <option value="Value2">Value2</option>
   <option value="Value3">Value3</option>
</select>
```

And the elements to get a class added:

```
 <div id="value1"></div>
 <div id="value2"></div>
 <div id="value3"></div>
```

And my function so far (almost working):

```
var trigger = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');
for (var i =0; i < trigger.length; i++) {
    var btn = trigger[i];
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        document.querySelector('#' + id).classList.toggle('active');    
    }, false);
}
```

I think the trouble I'm having is that I'm calling the function using click event listener. I guess I would need to use an `onchange` function instead?

Also I only want a single div to have an "active" class at any given time. At the moment, the function is adding the class but not removing it when another is selected.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2Rcjt/1/

**Note - I don't want to put any inline `onclick` JS in my markup.**

Comment: Yes !, you need to use `change`  instead of click `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/2Rcjt/3/

Comment: But then they all simultaneously get added. There should be only 1 item toggled at a time.

Comment: Maybe remove the class on all of them before adding it?

Comment: Ok I managed to pull it off by removing all the "active" classes first. However, the only way I could do it is by queryiing each of the IDs. http://jsfiddle.net/2Rcjt/5/ I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the last selected option (`div`) into some property of the select. Then each time user change the option, just toggle class on the last selected option to make it inactive. Code:

```
var trigger = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');
for(var i = 0; i < trigger.length; i++){
  trigger[i].onchange = function(){    
    if(this.lastOption) this.lastOption.classList.toggle('active');        
    this.lastOption = document.getElementById(this.value);    
    this.lastOption.classList.toggle('active');    
  };
  trigger[i].onchange();
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/2Rcjt/7/)

Comment: Thanks a heap! I really gotta level up my JS skills

Comment: @user3143218 you're welcome, surely you will improve your skill :)

Comment: Hey, sorry this is a bit late. How could I change the function so that it gets the actual selected select text rather than the value?

Comment: @user3143218 if you want to get the text of the selected option, you have 2 ways: the first is to access to the selected option using `selectedIndex` property like this `selectedText = this[this.selectedIndex].innerText` (replacing the `this.value` in the answer's code), the second way (a bit longer) is `selectedText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerText`.